# Proving induced voltages will always cancel in circuit that is in a $B$-field

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-circuits

Is there a way to conceptually prove that no matter the shape of the wire, when it is completely inside a $B$-field the induced voltages will cancel (without having to use the right-hand rule an infinite number of times)?

Answer (score 1):

The induced voltage will definitely not cancel in general. That is the entire point of magnetic induction. Unless you specify that the field is constant and the wires don't move, it is actually quite hard to construct systems of conductors that do not suffer from induction currents.

Answer (score 0):

The induce voltage is calculated by the change of magnetic flux, if neither the area nor B changes you have no induced voltage

Comment: Thanks for your comment. So are you saying that if I put a loop in a B-field at move it then a current will be generated? However, don't the voltages cancel each other?

Comment: A current will be induced if you change the area of the loop,  than different parts of the loop have different velocities , no current is induced if you just move the unchanged loop .

Comment: Thanks so much for your comment! So, if are moving the entire loop though a uniform B-field at a constant velocity, then there the induced voltages will be equal and opposite. Consider that if I accelerate the entire loop though the uniform B-field then there would be a zero voltage in the loop since all parts of the loop are moving have at the same instantaneous velocity.